# how to implement a video background behind app menu - Android

Tags: android, video

I want to play a video  in the background of my app...

In the menu, and as a splashscreen. Kinda like  the one that's on myspace.com

How to do this while maintaining  decent performance and keeping the UI responsive?

Answer (score 0):

You will use RelativeLayout n then put your video in VideoView on RelativeLayout... now you can easily put any things like Button, EditText etc as you want on VideoView....
some example as following....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But won't this just place the video at one place and buttons somewhere else... I want the buttons on the video, cutting across it. Also, what is requestfocus? I see only the end tag...

Comment: Here [link](http://s.slideme.org/files/imagecache/screenshot-normal/screenshots/08/53/2093750-660798.jpg?_cid=1362406633) I show "Club Ufone Video List" Image over the video.....
Do you mean exactly like that?

Comment: requestfocus is generally use in EditText for focus on that EditText....
i.e
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

Due to requestFocus tag cursor will be on that particular EditText in which requestFocus has been used.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Sham Yes, something like that ! Video playing in the background and a slightly transparent menu (just buttons) in front of it...